# Issue in setting five horizontal buttons in auto layout

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I am using auto layout to create five buttons at the bottom of the view.The layout looks like below where the brown colour shows the spacer view and number shows the buttons I am using.[image]

When I set the constraints I find that for iPhone the views are not resizing and we are missing the buttons as in the below screen shot.[image] The buttons are hidden and are not resizing.

When I run it on iPad the last spacer view is resizing and other[image]

Also, there are some errors in the logs that i am unable to understand can see below.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d62320 H:[UIView:0x7f8673f08c40]-(398)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f8673f08970 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d623c0 UIView:0x7f8673f08c40.leading == UIView:0x7f8673f08970.leadingMargin + 86>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d7c1e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7f8673f08970(414)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d623c0 UIView:0x7f8673f08c40.leading == UIView:0x7f8673f08970.leadingMargin + 86>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-12-29 13:00:54.932 Browser_Test[2480:60168] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d62b60 H:|-(446)-[UIView:0x7f8673d48640]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f8673f08970 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d62bb0 UIView:0x7f8673f08970.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x7f8673d53450'5'.trailing + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d62c00 H:[UIView:0x7f8673d48640]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7f8673d53450'5']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d7c1e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7f8673f08970(414)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8673d62c00 H:[UIView:0x7f8673d48640]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7f8673d53450'5']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

So can please some body suggest me whats getting wrong.

**Edit:1**

[image]
[image]

**Edit:2**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Replace spacer 1 and 5 with leading space and trailing space.

Comment: Remove width of buttons and add leading and trailing between thems. 1 button leading to superview, 5 button trailing to superview. If you've some view above or below buttons make constraint between thems.(bottom and top) if you have only superview, add with it...

Comment: Ctrl+drag from the button left side to the another button and click horizontal Spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons should all have pinned width. Button 1 should be set leading to the superview and trailing to spacer 1. Button 5 should be set leading to spacer 4 and trailing to the superview. Other buttons should be set leading and trailing to the adjacent spacers. All of the spacers should be set to have equal width to spacer 1.

Now, autolayout will resize the spacer views, all at the same time, to fill the available space as they don't have a specified width but the buttons do and they also have set edges (for buttons 1 and 5).

Comment: Thanks wain for the response.I am trying to go by that way.Can you please tell how to understand the errors of NSLayoutConstraint as what I have shown in logs.

Comment: The errors tell you that you have asked for something impossible. The table view is trying to set the width and your contents are trying to prevent it. Specifically it looks like you have explicitly set some view widths (414) which should be flexible.

Comment: I tried it but actually getting the same issue.Can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Can you show what you tried, either the code or an image of the constraints when a view is selected.

Comment: I meant the constraint lines overlaid on the view really as that shows the width equality settings between the spacing views and that would seem to be the missing piece. Certainly what you have shown in the edit has no equal width settings. It also helps to name the views so you can read the constraints and understand what they apply to (for the spacers).

Comment: Please see my edit after setting what you suggested I have done "reset to suggested constraints"  and it lead me to the above constraints.I am new to it so I hardly know about it.

Comment: Read this and see how to apply equal width constraints: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html